# Angular 2 access JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am struggling to access a local JSON file in my component file via JavaScript. In Angular 1, I would just make a service and inject it into my controller, but am lost with Angular 2.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. You can make a `http.get(...)` request to the server to get the file.

Comment: Requirement is the file is local, not on the server.  I'm unsure of how to get the data into the component to use it.

Comment: Something like http://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from local JSON file. First You need to get json data into varible using HttpClient

[Angular 2 HttpClient Official Docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)

then JSON data available to print Data

> if your **name** data in **jsonDATA** variable then

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let newData of jsonData">
{{newData.name}}
</li>
</ul>
```

If you get any error after this, then please ask with your sample error code

**Thanks**